# url blocked by whitelist HERE Maps

Tags: android, cordova, here-api

:) 
I try to integrate here maps javascript api and follow example from HERE maps sites https://developer.here.com/api-explorer. Then I test it using web preview and MBS from Worklight, the result is as expected (Map correctly displayed). But when i see the result in Android mobile device, the map is not displayed.

How can i solve this problem?

here is my index.html and main.js file:
main.js:

```
var map;
function wlCommonInit(){
    if(WL.Environment.PREVIEW != WL.Client.getEnvironment()){
        console.log("Used Cordova version is: " + device.cordova);
    }

    //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
      app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
      useCIT: true,
      useHTTPS: true
    });
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    //Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
    map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map);

    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
}

function moveMapToBerlin(){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>HereMapApp</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <button onclick="moveMapToBerlin();">map</button>
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey"></div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
I Attach the full log file from logcat here : http://pastebin.com/KN1GFMYZ

```
12-01 15:18:39.945: D/CordovaActivity(28650): onMessage(spinner,stop)
12-01 15:18:39.953: D/CordovaNetworkManager(28650): Connection Type: wifi
12-01 15:18:39.956: D/CordovaNetworkManager(28650): Connection Type: wifi
12-01 15:18:39.956: D/CordovaActivity(28650): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
12-01 15:18:39.990: D/CordovaLog(28650): : Line 0 : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
12-01 15:18:39.990: I/chromium(28650): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", source:  (0)
12-01 15:18:40.018: D/CordovaWebViewClient(28650): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
12-01 15:18:40.018: D/CordovaActivity(28650): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
12-01 15:18:40.233: W/PluginManager(28650): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to DeviceAuth.getDeviceUUID blocked the main thread for 174ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
12-01 15:18:40.262: D/CordovaLog(28650): file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js: Line 6 : Used Cordova version is: 3.4.0
12-01 15:18:40.262: I/chromium(28650): [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Used Cordova version is: 3.4.0", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js (6)
12-01 15:18:40.464: D/CordovaLog(28650): file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js: Line 46 : Used Android Cordova version is: 3.4.0
12-01 15:18:40.464: I/chromium(28650): [INFO:CONSOLE(46)] "Used Android Cordova version is: 3.4.0", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js (46)
12-01 15:18:40.538: D/NONE(28650): ondeviceready event dispatched
12-01 15:18:40.540: D/NONE(28650): wlclient init started
12-01 15:18:40.542: D/NONE(28650): Read cookies: null
12-01 15:18:40.545: W/NONE(28650): Note that if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
12-01 15:18:40.548: D/NONE(28650): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
12-01 15:18:40.551: D/NONE(28650): after: initOptions.onSuccess
12-01 15:18:40.553: D/NONE(28650): added onPause event handler 
12-01 15:18:40.555: D/NONE(28650): before: initOptions.onSuccess
12-01 15:18:40.559: D/NONE(28650): wlclient init success
12-01 15:18:40.731: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///bbbb0428-df73-4c7e-a969-f8ea45913234
12-01 15:18:40.734: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///e0194112-fd69-45c9-a34f-f7ffef324a68
12-01 15:18:40.955: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///6814f68e-33da-4012-8442-d1042f89ae7a
12-01 15:18:41.123: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///c7528252-cf1b-4568-98a9-95adc55ddde5
12-01 15:18:41.361: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///1fca0729-a44f-408b-8162-5a37a9bf5b6f
12-01 15:18:41.566: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///555a087f-be43-4bea-b2c0-84332c0e30cd
12-01 15:18:44.754: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///10b8291c-5b81-4530-a8c4-44cfd39bb659
12-01 15:18:44.770: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///b3c6d0d4-a179-47d4-8d91-ed8f6bb05182
12-01 15:18:44.778: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///8ff79fe1-457a-44ee-821f-6ac4d538e34b
12-01 15:18:44.780: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///4ea403d6-6a04-4336-b38f-44768416733e
12-01 15:18:44.782: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///792806d2-0eda-4a72-a35a-28c7a16aaab2
12-01 15:18:44.784: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///d325460d-9335-4a6f-bc76-9bf15252eefa
12-01 15:18:44.978: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///03d72c4c-b835-444f-8cea-08c268b8df0a
12-01 15:18:44.998: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///a06ddf31-8d0d-497b-9014-0b50e5594b32
12-01 15:18:45.059: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///9c61eaa2-51a3-48c8-a0e2-6964cc11c642
12-01 15:18:45.066: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///ee88dbe1-ff90-4eba-abd2-69844b8da755
12-01 15:18:45.076: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///0b177836-c385-4bc2-b270-33dcfcc066be
12-01 15:18:45.081: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///387075ce-8fdc-4810-aeaf-94913041bee0
12-01 15:18:45.275: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///1c44ac9b-caca-4fe8-8e6e-7bcc7bd2a65f
12-01 15:18:45.322: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///11e6def0-8b7b-4f24-b5a6-9ca886ef1aae
12-01 15:18:45.328: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///6b10848e-459e-4eb2-935c-f20b9201f262
12-01 15:18:45.332: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///ce08378e-dc05-4b45-8f01-9f1cc16bea80
12-01 15:18:45.337: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///7fdabe92-35a3-4fe7-991d-998fde206247
12-01 15:18:45.341: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///862be287-ee88-4ae8-a0b1-15d6942ef674
12-01 15:18:45.597: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///e5cbcb70-8c13-4d5d-bc9a-11b411ee6eae
12-01 15:18:45.604: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///b71ab981-ba05-4123-9173-b0ac823e3714
12-01 15:18:45.612: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///45450213-10f8-42d5-86cb-a08345739fa0
12-01 15:18:45.618: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///8d704eb2-c8f7-49ed-8065-b04467f5dfda
12-01 15:18:45.625: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///e423d272-470b-4688-9976-7f2f12f8cdb9
12-01 15:18:45.633: W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(28650): URL blocked by whitelist: blob:file%3A///706dcb3e-33d6-4c5d-a7cc-67adc6eb26be
12-01 15:19:45.209: D/CordovaActivity(28650): Paused the application!
12-01 15:19:45.209: D/CordovaWebView(28650): Handle the pause
12-01 15:19:45.211: D/WLClient(28650): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityPaused in WLClient.java:1215 :: on activity paused com.HereMapApp.HereMapApp . activity count = 0
12-01 15:19:45.227: D/NONE(28650): Flush called
12-01 15:19:45.249: D/WLClient(28650): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivitySaveInstanceState in WLClient.java:1227 :: on activity save instance state com.HereMapApp.HereMapApp
12-01 15:19:45.251: D/WLClient(28650): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStopped in WLClient.java:1239 :: on activity stopped com.HereMapApp.HereMapApp
```

**UPDATE**
This is my android cordova config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "HereMapApp"
        version   = "1.0.0.0">
    <name>HereMapApp</name>

    <description>
        HereMapApp
    </description>

    <author href="http://mycompany.com" email="application author's e-mail">
        application's author
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->
    <!-- This is required for native Android hooks -->
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.devicemotion.AccelListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.deviceorientation.CompassListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>         
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>    
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.batterystatus.BatteryListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature> 
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>    
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>                            

    <feature name="WLInitializationPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <!-- Due to bug in cordova next feature must set "onload" to false -->
   <feature name="UserAuth">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.UserAuthPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="false" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="LoggerPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.LoggerPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLApp">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLApp" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NativePage">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.NativePage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NativeBusyIndicator">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.BusyIndicator" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SecurityPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.SecurityPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="StoragePlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.StoragePlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Push">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WebResourcesDownloader">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WebResourcesDownloaderPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkDetector">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.NetworkDetector" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="DeviceAuth">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DeviceAuthPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WifiPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WifiPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLGeolocationPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLGeolocationPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="ForegroundBinderPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.ForegroundBinderPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FIPSHttpPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.FIPSHttpPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLCustomDialog">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLCustomDialog" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLSplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLSplashScreenPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLDirectUpdatePlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLDirectUpdatePlugin" />
    </feature>
     <feature name="WLNativeXHRPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLActionSenderPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLActionSenderPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLTrusteer">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLTrusteerPlugin" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

I've tried to add `<access origin="blob:*" launch-external="true" />`
But still no luck, i also tried to add

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="blob:*" />
```

But the result is still the same.

Please help me solve this problem, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you think that logcat is relevant? Add the full log file.

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar thx for reply, i've updated my question with full log file. i hope you can help me to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the HERE Maps API for JavaScript [Developer's Guide](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/common/credentials.html), you need to use your own `app_id` and `app_code` when writing your code. You can obtain a pair of credentials to test your app [here](https://developer.here.com/plans/api/consumer-mapping), just replace the code in the section below:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      app_id: '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
      app_code: '{YOUR_APP_CODE}',
      useCIT: true,
      useHTTPS: true
    });
```

The `DemoAppId01082013GAL` app id used in your code above is not white-listed for general use.

Comment: Hi Jason Fox, thx for your answer :) i've obtained my pair of credentials and put it as you've instructed, but the result is still the same.  I tried to create another worklight environment and test it on iOS and Blackberry 10 and the map is displayed correctly, the problem only happen on Android. Did i miss something?  :(